# "sh: exec: telnet: not found" - High Sierra

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, command-line

I've just completed updating to High Sierra. I've also successfully installed GNS3 (Network Simulator for Cisco studies) on High Sierra. I get the following message in the console while trying to access the CLI for the network devices with iTerm.

```
sh-3.2$ exec telnet 192.168.56.101 5000
sh: exec: telnet: not found
```

The following message shows up when I try and use Terminal.

```
-bash: telnet: command not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin. The reply to that post asks for compiling yourself. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The second part says it's available ready-packaged from homebrew. Either way, it's gone from native macOS since HS.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin. I've done what you suggested. I'm able to now access the CLI using Terminal. However I still get this message while trying to access the router CLI with Iterm. Any idea what I should be doing to get it working in Iterm?

sh-3.2$ exec telnet 192.168.56.101 5000
sh: exec: telnet: not found
sh-3.2$

Comment: So If I  go into the bash and try and telnet, it works. 

MacBook-Pro:~ RP$ telnet 192.168.56.101 5000
Trying 192.168.56.101...
Connected to 192.168.56.101.
Escape character is '^]'.

IOU1#
IOU1#
IOU1#

However, when I click router icon to bring up the CLI in iterm, the prompt is a non root shell.

sh-3.2$ exec telnet 192.168.56.101 5001
sh: exec: telnet: not found
sh-3.2$

I wonder if the prompt not being root shell could be causing the issue?

Comment: If you installed telnet with Homebrew and it is working from the prompt but not from your tool, I would guess some path issue. Try getting the path for `telnet` by executing `which telnet` from the prompt and using the full path in your tool, instead of only `telnet`.

Comment: Thanks Ipacheco! 

This is what I get when I type in which telnet in terminal

"/usr/local/bin/telnet"

I cannot find any option in the preferences for iTerm that can be used to specify the above path. What command should I run in iTerm to change the path to "/usr/local/bin/telnet"?

Comment: NVM! I got it. Thank you! Had to make the change in GNS3.